# New billing fields not showing on User page (Poor Guys Swiss Knife plugin for WooCommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

Using Poor Guys Swiss Knife plugin for WooCommerce, I created 3 new Billing fields: birthday (date), newsletter (select: yes/no) and terms & conditions (select: yes/no). I successfully registered as a new customer on the site and filled these new fields.

However when checking the account thus created in the dashboard, I see all the regular fields except the 3 ones I created with the Poor Guys Swiss Knife plugin. Why is that ?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly plugin is not sending fields data to user account.

You can achieve same results using woocommerce custom fields in your functions.php file.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

To make it required use this code:

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
```

you can find more on this website:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Thanks, but although the field does appear during checkout process, it still doesn't show up on the dashboard Users page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I came up with and it has been working fine for me, hope it helps you as well.

I created a few new fields for the billing form using that plugin but let's just use one as an example:

-Resale License # ( billing_resale_license_ )

Now, the plugin ( or the code from the first answer ) will add the field to the form for you, in my case, I end up with:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_resale_license_" id="billing_resale_license_" placeholder="" value="" display="text">
```

Now, we need to save the value of that field to the user_meta table, like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'ws_billing_fields_save', 10, 1 );

function ws_billing_fields_save( $user_id ){
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_resale_license_'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_resale_license_', $_POST['billing_resale_license_']);
    }
}
```

Now that data is stored in user_meta, we need to hook in to the profile area to display it and allow it to be edited by the user or admins.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'ws_update_user_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'ws_update_user_profile' );

function ws_update_user_profile( $user ){ ?>
<h3>Additional Fields</h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="billing_resale_license_">Resale #</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="billing_resale_license_" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'billing_resale_license_', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_fields' );

function save_extra_fields( $user_id ){
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'billing_resale_license_', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_resale_license_'] ) );
}
```

I chose to break my additional fields into their own table just above the default Woocommerce fields as I have many of them and they are more specific to the user rather than the order processing itself, so I keep them organized in their own table titled "Additional Fields".

Answer (score 0):

I think the billing fields are visible on the order only, not the user. User fields are available through the `register_form` and `user_register` hooks.